# Jquery Grid layout Drag and Drop Resize

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, resize

I'm trying to do drag and drop resizable layout from     http://gridster.net/ .As of it everything works fine for dragging,dropping and resize

```
<div class="gridster">
<ul>
<li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>

<li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1"></li>
<li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2"></li>
</ul>
</div> 
<script>
    $(function(){ //DOM Ready

    $(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins: [10, 10],
    widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
    });

    }); 
</script>
```

But during run time the 'ul' gets style of height,width and position as per the list of items.I want to override the run time height and width of 'ul'.If any thing please suggest me thanks in advance....!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the values using the events `draggable.stop` but that might create a problem when their value is less than the margin you had given.